# Magento 2 class not exist error occurs when overriding a controller

Tags: magento2, di.xml

error:
a:4:{i:0;s:68:"Class namespace\modulename\Controller\CustomLoginPost does not exist";i:1;s:6711:"#0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('namespace\modulename...')

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" type="namespace\modulename\Controller\Account\CustomLoginPost" /> 
</config>
```

anyone can help? I have checked the path is correct, the module is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

First your di.xml check for xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation value. in magento 2 latest CE, xml value are changed.Your di.xml contains old value.

Your config tag look like below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
```

set above line in di.xml file.
Framework folder files and magento core module  are reside in root/vendor/magento folder.
So keep path updated in your di file.

Thanks.